# Grails register a DateMarshaller in BootStrap,throws Exception that rails.converters.JSON cannot be cast to grails.converters.XML

Tags: json, grails, classcastexception

Grails version:2.3.8  I registered a custom date marshaller in *BootStrap.groovy*, however when I use Object which has Date filled as Json, it will throw a Exception: Exception message is

```
ClassCastException: grails.converters.JSON cannot be cast to grails.converters.XML.
```

*BootStrap.goovy*:

```
def customDateMarshaller = new DateMarshaller(FastDateFormat.getInstance("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault()))
def init = { servletContext ->
   JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(customDateMarshaller)`
}
```

Comment: What version of Grails?

Comment: Grails version:2.3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my problems. There are two classes having same simple class name ,DateMarshaller.
one is '`org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.xml.DateMarshaller`',the another is '`org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.DateMarshaller`'.We should use second one instead of first one